# UICollectionViewCell doesn't fill the screen

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a `UIViewController` containing a `UICollectionView` for vertical paging. The `UICollectionView` (blue area in the picture) is pinned to the top of the superview, but `UICollectionViewCell` (yellow) is not. I tried to explicitly pin the top constraint of the `UICollectionViewCell` to the top of `UICollectionView` but the program crashes.

[image: Collection view (blue area) is filling the screen but the view cell (yellow) is misplaced]

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect.zero, collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
    collectionView.register(FeedCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    collectionView.backgroundColor = .blue
    collectionView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
    collectionView.isPagingEnabled = true
    
    view.addSubview(collectionView)
    
    collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
      collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
      collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
      view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: collectionView.bottomAnchor),
      view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: collectionView.trailingAnchor)
    ])
    
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.delegate = self
  }
  
  override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    .lightContent
  }
  
  // MARK: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
  
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: collectionView.bounds.height)
  }
  
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
  }
  
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
  }
}

extension HomeViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
  func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    1
  }


  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    4
  }

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)
    cell.backgroundColor = indexPath.item % 2 == 0 ? .yellow : .orange
    
    return cell
  }
  
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
  }
}
```

Comment: So this is exactly why `safeArea` exists, for you to attach things to. it would seem that the default layout you are using (`UICollectionViewFlowLayout`) recognizes safe area insets. creating the gap you highlighted.

Answer (score 4):

Just pin your collection view to the top of View, not to the safeArea

```
collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true;
```

And use to just your collection view to safe area insets:

```
collectionView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never;
```

Comment: Changing `contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior` to `.never` did the trick for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of pinning to all safe area edges using `pinEdgesToSafeArea(to:)`  you should pin the top constraint of the collection view to the top constraint of `view`. I don't know where `pinEdgesToSafeArea(to:)` comes from so can't comment on a replacement for that but you can use this to pin your collection view to the top of the screen:

```
collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
```

Edit:
based on the clarifications you've posted, try setting `automaticallyAdjustsScrollIndicatorInsets`  to `false`:

```
collectionView.automaticallyAdjustsScrollIndicatorInsets = false
```

[docs for more info](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/3198043-automaticallyadjustsscrollindica)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I updated the code and the question description. As you can see the top constraint of the collection view is already pinned to the top of `view` as shown by the blue part. It's the collection cell (yellow) that is not pinned to the top of `view`. When I try to auto constraint the collection cell, the program crashes